# Mac freezes, rainbow wheel, etc

Tags: color, osx

I installed Blender in a 2011 Mac High Sierra for my son to learn it.
It had been running fine but when he began adding colors, the Mac started to freeze with the rainbow wheel (of death). It takes a good minute for the Mac to react again.
However, the color in the figure is not what was chosen. My son chose yellow and here you have all green with super strange green effect in the figurine's arms (photo).
Can you please help out?
[image: Should have been flat yellow, but look! :(]

Comment: It looks like it might be related to graphics drivers. Try updating them.

Comment: Please provide all the relevant information about the problem. [Share full unclipped screenshots](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/mac.html) with all the interface visible as well as [the .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). tell us about what is done before the problem occurs and if it repeats with other scenes or other Blender versions.